# show that the space of continuous and bounded functions is connected

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, continuity

Provided a metric space X, I have to prove that the space of continuous and bounded functions whose domain is real numbers, denoted by C*(X) is connected, I tried to get a contradiction by supposing that there exist two non-empty and closed set $ X,Y \subset C^*(X) $ such that $ X \cap Y =\emptyset $ and $  X \cup Y =C^*(X)$ but then I realized that I have no idea how subsets of $ C^*(X)$ looks like.
So I wanna ask you for bibliographycal references or any intuition to get a better idea of this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It seems that you can do this for every topological space $X$.

Comment: You did not specify any topology on the space so connectedness does not make sense. BTW any normed linear space (or any t.v.s) is path connected so if you are using the sup norm the space is connected .

Comment: Thanks for your response Kavi, the teacher just told us that the topology of any metric space (X,d) is the set of all open sets of X under the metric d.
About your response can you give me another hint to solve this question? ; Since I cannot use path connected 'cause is not a definition given in the course.
Thank you.

Comment: Paul I didn't get your comment.
Could you be more explicit please?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: If $f,g$ are continuous and bounded so is $tf+(1-t)g, t\in\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Hi Aristide, Could u give me another hint, since the definition of path connected was not given in the course so I can't use it.Thank you.